# How to automatically call a another method in a class with result of the called method when a method is called?

Tags: php

I have a class with few methods like this..

```
class ClassA
{
    public functon funcA(arguments) : bool
    {
        // return true or false
    }

    public functon funcB(arguments) : bool
    {
        // return true or false
    }


    private function ifFalse(){ // do something }
}
```

What i want to do is call `ifFalse()` method automatically when `funcA()` or `funcB()` are called and they return false.

How can I achive this?
I am using php 7 by the way.

Comment: Why don't you call ifFalse() manually in funcA() before returning false?

Comment: Personally - calling something explicitly is better than 'something just happens if some condition is met'.  Means anyone can understand the code rather than having to be psychic.

Comment: I can't call `ifFlase` manually because I want to be able to add more of those true/false function as my application expands without worring about handeling ifFlase case in each one of them. I also want to do this to a parent class so every class that inherits this class has this logic out of the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the function inside the other function:

```
$ret = false;
// return true or false
if (!$ret) $this->ifFalse();
return $ret;
```

If you want it more "magic", you could do:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    switch($name) {
        case 'funcA':
        case 'funcB':
            $value = $this->$name(...$arguments);
            if (!$value) $this->ifFalse();
            return $value;
        break;
    }
}

private function funcA(arguments) : bool
{
    // return true or false
}

private function funcB(arguments) : bool
{
    // return true or false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used `method_exists` in if statement instead of `switch` to make it dynamic. But your answer was really helpful.